# Problema al visualizar dato seleccionado en campo select de vista edit.blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

En la vista edit.blade no logro que se visualice el dato seleccionado previamente en la vista create.blade.

Aqui dejo el codigo de la vista Create del campo Tipo de Incidencia:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Tipo de Incidencia</label>
                <select name="Tipo_incidencia" id="Tipo_incidencia" class="form-control">
                      <option value="" selected>Seleccionar</option>
                      <option value="Primer Ingreso">Primer Ingreso</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Receta Mensual">Ing. Receta Mensual</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Receta Complementaria">Ing. Receta Complementaria</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Seguimiento">Ing. Seguimiento</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Co-Pago">Ing. Co-Pago</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Partida Defuncion">Ing. Partida Defunción</option>
                      <option value="Suspension de Tratamiento">Suspensión de Tratamiento</option>
                      <option value="Sentencia Revocada">Sentencia Revocada</option>
                </select>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Y aqui dejo el mismo campo pero de la vista edit, es igual al de la vista create porque justamente no se como hacer para solucionar dicho problema:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Tipo de Incidencia</label>
                <select name="Tipo_incidencia" id="Tipo_incidencia" class="form-control">
                      <option value="Primer Ingreso">Primer Ingreso</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Receta Mensual">Ing. Receta Mensual</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Receta Complementaria">Ing. Receta Complementaria</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Seguimiento">Ing. Seguimiento</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Co-Pago">Ing. Co-Pago</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Partida Defuncion">Ing. Partida Defunción</option>
                      <option value="Suspension de Tratamiento">Suspensión de Tratamiento</option>
                      <option value="Sentencia Revocada">Sentencia Revocada</option>
                </select>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En la vista de EDIT tiene que haber una variable que contenga la información del **Tipo de Incidencia** que se seleccionó en el CREATE para que puedas compararlo

Supongamos que es una variable ($incidencia) que posee el nombre de la incidencia seleccionada en CREATE, el código te quedaría algo así usando los condicionales de balde

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tipo de Incidencia</label>
        <select name="Tipo_incidencia" id="Tipo_incidencia" class="form-control">
            <option {{$incidencia=="Primer Ingreso"?"selected":""}} value="Primer Ingreso">Primer Ingreso</option>
            <option {{$incidencia=="Ing. Receta Mensual"?"selected":""}} value="Ing. Receta Mensual">Ing. Receta Mensual</option>
            <option {{$incidencia=="Ing. Receta Complementaria"?"selected":""}} value="Ing. Receta Complementaria">Ing. Receta Complementaria</option>
            <option {{$incidencia=="Ing. Seguimiento"?"selected":""}} value="Ing. Seguimiento">Ing. Seguimiento</option>
            <option {{$incidencia=="Ing. Co-Pago"?"selected":""}} value="Ing. Co-Pago">Ing. Co-Pago</option>
            <option {{$incidencia=="Ing. Partida Defuncion"?"selected":""}} value="Ing. Partida Defuncion">Ing. Partida Defunción</option>
            <option {{$incidencia=="Suspension de Tratamiento"?"selected":""}} value="Suspension de Tratamiento">Suspensión de Tratamiento</option>
            <option {{$incidencia=="Sentencia Revocada"?"selected":""}} value="Sentencia Revocada">Sentencia Revocada</option>
         </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Modifique el codigo como tu me dices pero sigue igual